# How to show data (in front of every content) in div if content come in huge lines in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am getting data from server (at regular intervals of time ). I need to show some text in front of every line. So I think if there is a change in height then I append data in front div. But it's not working, because some time huge amount of data is coming from server (mean two or three line come once) there is change in height. But it append only once.

so my result look like this

```
Text                     Server  data
changed Hiiiii.  is i am checking this in the div
        please check me also and everty thing is 
        fine well know dive sdsfdsfsdfdfsdfdsfdsfsd
changed Hiiiii.  is i am checking this in the div
        please check me also and everty thing is 
        fine well know dive sdsfdsfsdfdfsdfdsfdsfsd
```

**But I need my result to look like this**

```
Text                     Server  data
changed Hiiiii.  is i am checking this in the div
changed please check me also and everty thing is 
changed  fine well know dive sdsfdsfsdfdfsdfdsfdsfsd
changed Hiiiii.  is i am checking this in the div
changed please check me also and everty thing is 
changed fine well know dive sdsfdsfsdfdfsdfdsfdsfsd
```

I try in this way. Maybe I will get 100 lines at once. But I need to show 100 times text in front of content.

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/dRrnX/

```
$(function() {
    var h = -1;
    setInterval(function () {
        var newHeight = $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii.  is i am checking this in the div please check me also and everty thing is fine well know div").height();
        if (h == -1) h = newHeight;
        if (h != newHeight) {
            h = newHeight;
            $('#realTimeContents1').append(" changed ");
            //alert("I've changed height");
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the timeout if I may ask?

Comment: I am using timer function because to understand coder that I am getting data from server at regular interval of time

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
.data .status,
.data .text {
    float: left;
}
.data .status {
    width: 25%;
}
.data .status span {
    display: block;
}
.data .text {
    width: 75%;
}

<section class='data'>
    <div class='status'><span>Changed</span></div>
    <div class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce condimentum blandit neque. Nulla facilisi. Sed ornare luctus nulla euismod tincidunt. Cras rhoncus semper mi vitae facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam feugiat quis dui sit amet pretium. Nunc et accumsan risus, non lobortis mi. Donec pulvinar lacus diam, eu feugiat tortor malesuada a. Aenean pretium quam mi, id tincidunt nulla posuere nec</div>
</section>

var $data = $('.data');

$data.each(function e(){
    var $text = $(this).children('.text'),
        $status = $text.prev('.status'),
        $span = $status.children('span'),
        height = $text.height();

    while ($status.height() < height) {
        $status.append($span.clone());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mJfjN/

Note, it is fairly easy to create an infinite loop, so be careful.

**EDIT**

`$(window).resize()`:

```
$(window).resize(changed);

changed();

function changed() {
    $('.data').each(change);

    function change(){
        var $text = $(this).children('.text'),
            $status = $text.prev('.status'),
            $span = $status.children('span:first'),
            height = $text.height();

        $span.siblings().remove();

        while ($status.height() < height) {
            $status.append($span.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mJfjN/4/

Comment: Save that as a function and set that to run `$(window).resize()`. You'll need to reset the `.status span` to the first each time, or something along those lines.

Comment: Your example is correct .but you take static data (a div having fix) data .but I am getting data from server .

Comment: @Rohit look at the second comment on this answer. He said exactly what needs to be done. You've got some work left to do, but it's minor.

Comment: @Itay - I provided the example in a new fiddle.

Comment: You probably meant to address @Rohit :)